# Vue v-for conditional styling

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use `v-for` to create buttons. I add the .active class if `isActiveButton()` returns true:

```html
<button 
  v-for="(text, index) in this.buttonOptions" 
  class="btn" 
  :class="{active: isActiveButton(text)}" 
  :value='text' 
  @mousedown.prevent @click="some_method">
    {{text}}
</button>
```

What is the best way to add the .active class to the first button if `isActive()` returns `false` for **all** `buttonOptions`? Note that the `buttonOptions` is a prop.

Comment: Is that `,` supposed to be there before the `:value`?

Comment: edit code block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Computed Property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) would be the way to go!

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttonOptions: ['button1', 'button2', 'button3', 'button4']
  },
  methods: {
    isActiveButton: function (text) {
      return (text === text.toUpperCase());
    },
    some_method: function() {
      console.log('Button clicked')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    shouldFirstBeActive: function () {
      return (this.buttonOptions.filter(el => this.isActiveButton(el))).length === 0
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section>
    <button 
      v-for="(text, index) in buttonOptions" 
      class="btn" 
      :class="{active: isActiveButton(text) || (shouldFirstBeActive && index === 0)}" 
      :value='text' 
      @mousedown.prevent @click="some_method">
        {{text}}
    </button>
  </section>
</div>
```

I don't know what the methods `isActiveButton` do, so I had to improvise: It checks if the string is uppercase.

What does the trick is the computed property `shouldFirstBeActive` which returns `true` if all the items in the `buttonOptions` array fails the `isActiveButton` method:

```
return (this.buttonOptions.filter(el => this.isActiveButton(el))).length === 0
```

If you change the `button2` to BUTTON2 for example, then the `isActiveButton` returns `true` for that item, which renders the `shouldFirstBeActive` computed property to `false`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttonOptions: ['button1', 'BUTTON2', 'button3', 'button4']
  },
  methods: {
    isActiveButton: function (text) {
      return (text === text.toUpperCase());
    },
    some_method: function() {
      console.log('Button clicked')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    shouldFirstBeActive: function () {
      return (this.buttonOptions.filter(el => this.isActiveButton(el))).length === 0
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section>
    <button 
      v-for="(text, index) in buttonOptions" 
      class="btn" 
      :class="{active: isActiveButton(text) || (shouldFirstBeActive && index === 0)}" 
      :value='text' 
      @mousedown.prevent @click="some_method">
        {{text}}
    </button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed that filters  this.buttonOptions where isActiveButton is true and that takes index as a parameter